# How to load ViewController after passing notification

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, uilocalnotification

When my application closes I set a `UILocalNotification` depending on `Core-Data` and a link to the `NSManagedObject` is saved in the `userInfo` property. This works fine.

Then when the `UILocalNotification` fires, and the user swipes it, the app loads and I use `NSNotificationCenter` to successfully pass the `userInfo` to my `MainViewController`. This works fine.

Here I use `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation` to find the `Core-Data` object and run `performSegue` to display the `DetailViewController`. This works fine **IF** the user closed the application while on the `MainViewController`

My problem however is depending on where the user is in the application when they exit.

Say for example they exit while viewing the `SettingsViewController`, then when they access the `UILocalNotification` it will slide the `DetailViewController` on top of the `SettingsViewController`. It is nice that they see the correct Object however I would prefer that the back button took them back to `MainViewController`

The same goes for if they are in a `UIViewController` 3 or 4 layers deep into the `DetailViewController` and exit. When they access the `UILocalNotification` it slides the `DetaiViewController` on top of where they are. Again, I would prefer the application to collapse the previous `DetailViewController` and start a fresh.

Hope this makes sense. Not sure what to do other than try setting up lots of "unwind" segues that are triggered if a `UILocalNotification` is accessed. Is there a simpler and better approach?

## Update

Here is what i'm up to in `didReceiveLocalNotification`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    var state:UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
    if state == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        println("app del notification : \(notification.userInfo)")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kShowNotification, object: notification.userInfo)
    }
}
```

## Update

Ok, I like the idea of popping the 2 `UINavigationController`s (Master & Detail) connected to the `UISplitViewController` but not sure how to actually do this.

I've setup my subclassed `UISplitViewController` to receive an `NSNotificationCenter` message. However this count is always 1:

```
// MARK: Notifications
func showEventNotication(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("split view controllers: \(self.viewControllers.count)")
}
```

Here is the current setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works for me (Swift 2.0).
I have TabBarController and NavigationController + ViewControllers.
When app receive the localNotification and after tap to button it will show MyViewController.
In AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    if identifier == "showDetails" {

        let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0

        let myViewController = window?.rootViewController!.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as? MyViewController

        let controller = tabBarController.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
        controller.pushViewController(myViewController!, animated: false)
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the `UINavigationController` in your AppDelegate you can use the method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` to change the navigation stack.

If you have the reference to the `UINavigationController`simply call `[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]` to make it pop the stack, then push the `MainViewController` and then your `DetailViewController`just like you do now.

Comment: Could you please offer a bit more information? I actually have a `UISplitViewController` subclassed (e.g.: `MySplitViewController`). Would I do something in there after receiving the notification?

Comment: Added some more detail :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this before. I have a suggestion for you.

It's not good or not appropriate to inject view controller in current navigation hierarchy when notification finish. You can do a brach thing like if you know the `git` repository that maintains a separate brach for each clone/check out.

So you need to do just like this way. You are in a middle of something and notification shows up then leave current flow of navigation and start a new branch from that point.

So after all digging for this notification related flow at last you have node/junction to safely recover your previous flow of application (Like you said back & back will lead you to previous view controller before notification was received.)

The one way I think to doing of this is `presentViewController` from current view controller. I haven't try this but it will work.

Get current view controller in `didReceiveLocalNotification` method and present view controller which is link to notification here.

Pictorial Flow:

```
NavigationController ----> VC1 ---->  SettingsViewController
                                      /                  |
                                     /                   |
                                    /                    |
                                   /                     |   
                             Back /_______________   Notification received
                                 |                           |
                                 |                           | present view controller
                            Back |                           |   
                                 |                           V
                                 |                  NotificationViewController
                                 |                           |
                                 |                           V
                              Storage <----------------- Operations
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To be honest this is exactly the way the application is behaving right now. Where ever the user is in the app the notification view pops on top, they can then interact with the notification and eventually press back to continue what they are doing.

I'm half tempted to keep this design as it does make sense. Plus the fact I can't quite figure out the Navigation Controllers.